# Solr highlighting of tint field

Tags: solr

I am experiencing a strange problem with highlighting. I have a simple configuration roughly as follows:

```
<str name="defType">edismax</str>
<str name="qf">all_text</str>
...
<str name="hl">on</str>
<str name="hl.fl">*</str>
<bool name="hl.requireFieldMatch">false</bool>
```

I run the search on a single catch-all field called "all_text", and I want the highlighting to work on other fields in the document. That is why `requiredFieldMatch=false`,
All the other fields that are meant to be highlighted are indexed and stored, and they are copied to all_text with the `<copyField>` directive.

This works fine for text fields, however if the field is of type tint (TrieIntegerField) Solr doesn't return any highlight information for them.
E.g., I have this field:

```
<field name="age" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

and:

```
<copyField source="age" dest="all_text" />
```

but no highlighting for it in the search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Solr are you using? Looks like you are running into a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3050).

**Update**

You can try using a copyfield of type string for highlighting until the issue is resolved.

Comment: I am using solr 3.6. I think it you are right, it's the same problem as in Solr 4

Comment: This problem exists in 3.6 as well.